# For loop to create multiple plot sets with minor alterations

Tags: r, loops, histogram, boxplot

I have seven very similar data subsets from my main data source, split from data1 to data5.  How can I create a for loop so that all the plots are created simulatenously, rather than copying and pasting the code below and making slight alterations.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
hist(data1$value1, main=paste("Data 1 - Value 1 Histogram"), xlab="Value 1", col="lightblue", ylim=c(0,10), xlim=c(200,1000))
boxplot(data1$value1, varwidth = T, main=paste("Data 1 - Value 1 Box Plot"), xlab="Value 1", col="lightblue", horizontal=T, frame=F, ylim=c(200,1000))
hist(data1$value 2, main=paste("Data 1 - Value 2 Histogram"), xlab="Value 2", col="palegreen", ylim=c(0,10), xlim=c(30,50))
boxplot(data1$value 2, varwidth = T, main=paste("Data 1 - Value 2 Box Plot"), xlab="Value 2", col="palegreen", horizontal=T, frame=F, ylim=c(30,50))
```

Note: the only values I would need to change from 1:5 would be

```
hist(data[n]$value1/value2, main=paste("Data [n] - Value 1/Value 2 histogram/box plot")
```

as well as the ylim and xlim values to suit the scale.  I may choose to use the same scale throughout although some plots won't be clear, or I could use the default values I presume.

Answer (score 0):

Saving the five datasets within a `list` as it makes it easy to iterate across. You'll also need to add code to capture the plots as desired.

```
for (i in seq_along(lst)) {
  par(mfrow=c(2,2))
  with(lst[[i]], {
    hist(value1, main=sprintf("Data %i - Value 1 Histogram", i), xlab="Value 1", col="lightblue", ylim=c(0,10), xlim=c(min(value1), max(value1)))
    boxplot(value1, varwidth = TRUE, main=sprintf("Data %i - Value 1 Box Plot", i), xlab="Value 1", col="lightblue", horizontal=TRUE, frame=FALSE, ylim=c(min(value1), max(value1)))
    hist(value2, main=sprintf("Data %i - Value 2 Histogram", i), xlab="Value 2", col="palegreen", ylim=c(0,10), xlim=c(min(value2), max(value2)))
    boxplot(value2, varwidth = TRUE, main=sprintf("Data %i - Value 2 Box Plot", i), xlab="Value 2", col="palegreen", horizontal=TRUE, frame=FALSE, ylim=c(min(value2), max(value2)))
  })
  # add code to capture plots as desired
}
```